# scipy.optimize.minimize IndexError when trying to deblur an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scipy-optimize

```
def grad_f(X,b):
  g = AT(A(X,1)-b,1)
  return g

def f(X,b):
  ret = (linalg.norm((A(X,1)-b),2)**2)/2
  return ret
```

f is the function to minimize, grad_f is the gradient of that function.
AT and A are functions provided to me just for matrix multiplication and transposition purposes, I assume they are correct.
X is a 2D-array corresponding to a grayscale image and b is also a 2D-array containing the same image with blur+gaussian noise applied to it.
I have to use the scipy.optimize.minimize function using the conjugated gradient method.

```
res = minimize(fun=f, x0=X, args=(b), method='CG')
```

I get the following error when I try to call the minimize function:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ae4a698972d1> in <module>()
     10 
     11 f(X,b)
---> 12 minimize(f, X, args=(b), method='CG')
     13 #res = minimize(fun=grad_f, x0=X.shape, args=(b), method='CG')
     14 

13 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in fft2(*args, **kwargs)

<__array_function__ internals> in take(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     42     except AttributeError:
     43         wrap = None
---> 44     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
     45     if wrap:
     46         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):

IndexError: index -2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, it's hard to help properly.

Comment: Could you please include the full traceback in your question? Not just the last line of the error message.

Comment: @9769953
[Here](https://prnt.sc/26c19t4) is the screenshot of the traceback. Let me know if even the 13 frames are needed, thank you

Comment: Please copy-paste the traceback (and format it as code) into your question. Screenshots can't be copy-pasted, read by search engines or screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `linalg.norm((A(X,1)-b),2)`.
Since `A(X, 1)` must return a matrix (As `b` is a matrix) you should use something like `linalg.norm((A(X,1)-b), ord = ‘fro’)` in order to use a proper norm for matrices.